# hasClass() does not work in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am getting `Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method`
when I use IE8.

```
if (this.hasClass('imgchargelocation')) {
                CallPopUp($(this).closest('tr')[0].sectionRowIndex, 'chargelocation');
            }
```

I also tried this one but same error ..

```
if (this.attr('class', 'imgchargelocation')) {
                    CallPopUp($(this).closest('tr')[0].sectionRowIndex, 'chargelocation');
                }
```

hasClass seems to be working just fine in chrome.

Comment: what is `this` in the given context

Comment: i guess that the problem might be with `.sectionRowIndex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like You are using jQuery if yes then please fix your syntax like this

```
if ($(this).hasClass('imgchargelocation')) {
  CallPopUp($(this).closest('tr')[0].sectionRowIndex, 'chargelocation');
}
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks bro. Why is IE so stupid? Or may be I am :P

Comment: hasClass is jQuery method.